# Attaching UVM Analysis Ports Hierarchically

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a component that contains two subscribers.  I'd like to be able to instantiate that component and connect its subscribers without using a hierarchical reference.

Given that I have

```
my_comp.sub1.analysis_export
my_comp.sub2.analysis_export
```

How can I make connections to the subscribers inside the component without reaching into the component?

I'd like to be able to do

```
function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    monitor.ap1.connect(my_comp.sub_1_analysis_export);
    monitor.ap2.connect(my_comp.sub_2_analysis_export);
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an analysis export port in higher level hierarchy (my_comp class) and connect it to the sub_1.analysis export ports, in it's connect phase.

Now in the connect phase of agent, you can directly connect monitor analysis port to that new analysis export port. (I believe, you have written connect phase of the agent class, in your code, which is generally the normal location of monitor)

Your modified code may look like this :

```
// In my_comp Class
uvm_analysis_export #([Your Port Transaction Data Type]) new_export_1;
uvm_analysis_export #([Your Port Transaction Data Type]) new_export_2;

function void connect_phase();
  new_export_1.connect(sub1.analysis_export);
  new_export_2.connect(sub2.analysis_export);
endfunction

// In agent Class
function void connect_phase();
  monitor.ap1.connect(my_comp.new_export_1);
  monitor.ap2.connect(my_comp.new_export_2);
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create ports or exports at a higher level of the component hierarchy and connect them to ports and exports at the lower level. Then you connect the higher level components. Typically, a monitor is part of an agent, and you make the analysys_port of the monitor a port of the agent. Then you connect the subscriber to the agent.

Comment: so I call `sub1.analysis_export.connect(sub_1_analysis_export)` at the upper level?